# Prove that the polar decomposition of normal matrices, $A=SU$, is such that $SU=US$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Assume $A$ is a normal matrix. Suppose $A=SU$ is a polar decomposition of $A$. Prove that $SU=US$.

I have no idea to prove this.

$A$ is normal then $AA^*=A^*A$. And then we have
$$
SS^*=U^*S^*SU.
$$
But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: This post deals with 
"$\!A$ is a normal operator" $\Rightarrow$ "The factors in the polar decomp. of
$A$ commute." Note that normality is also a necessary condition, so that both conditions are equivalent  in fact. This is subject of a recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3139662/t-au-iff-t-is-a-normal-operator-on-hilbert-space) which refers to an exercise in J. Conway's book on Functional Analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\,A=U|A|$, then $\,A^*=|A|U^*$. By normality one obtains 
$$U|A|^2U^* = AA^* = A^*A = |A|^2,$$
an equality of positive-semidefinite matrices.

"Positive square-rooting" yields $\,U|A|U^* = |A|\;\Longleftrightarrow\; U|A| = |A|U$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that, since $A = SU$ is a polar decomposition, $S$ is (Hermitian and) positive semidefinite.

So, as you noted, we have
$$
SS^* = U^*S^*SU \implies\\
S^2 = U^* S^2U
$$
From here, note that each side is positive semidefinite and that the positive semidefinite square root of such a matrix is uniquely defined. As such, we can take the square root of both sides.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means to take the square root of a matrix? Moreover, how does the square root works when you have a similarity transformation as is the case on the final RHS. Would it work like this?
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{S^2} = \sqrt{U^* S^2 U} \\
S = U^* \sqrt{S^2} U \\
S = U^*SU
\end{align*}
If that is the case, why does $$\sqrt{U^* S^2 U} =U^* \sqrt{S^2} U$$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} A$ be a normal matrix. It is therefore unitarily diagonalisable, *i.e.* writable as
$$A = \sum_k c_k P_{\bs u_k}$$
for a set of orthogonal projectors $P_{\bs u_k}\equiv \bs u_k \bs u_k^*$, where $\langle \bs u_j,\bs u_k\rangle=\delta_{jk}$ (and thus $\operatorname{Tr}(P_{\bs u_j} P_{\bs u_k})=\delta_{jk}$) and complex coefficients $c_k\in\mathbb C$.

The corresponding [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (or more generally *one* possible choice of SVD) reads $A=UD V^\dagger$ with
$$
U = \sum_k e^{i\varphi_k} \bs u_k \bs e_k^*,\qquad
D=\sum_k |c_k| \bs e_k\bs e_k^*, \qquad
V=\sum_k \bs u_k \bs e_k^*,
$$
where $c_k\equiv |c_k|e^{i\varphi_k}$, and $\bs e_k$ are the basis vectors for some reference basis used to represent the matrices.

The *polar* decomposition reads $A=|A| U_A$ with
$$|A|\equiv UDU^\dagger= \sum_k |c_k| \bs u_k \bs u_k^*,
\qquad
U_A \equiv UV^\dagger = \sum_k e^{i\varphi_k} \bs u_k \bs u_k^*.$$
From this, it's clear that $|A|$ and $U_A$ commute, being them diagonal in the same basis.

---

It's worth seeing where exactly the above argument breaks in the case of non-normal matrices. For a generic matrix $A$ the SVD reads
$$A = UDV^\dagger = \sum_k p_k \bs u_k \bs v_k^*, \\
U\equiv \sum_k \bs u_k\bs e_k^*,
\qquad V \equiv \sum_k \bs v_k\bs e_k^*,
\qquad D \equiv \sum_k p_k \bs e_k \bs e_k^*,$$
for some positive coefficients $p_k>0$ and orthonormal sets $\{\bs u_k\}_k$ and $\{\bs v_k\}_k$. Then $A=|A| U_A$ with
$$|A| \equiv UD U^\dagger = \sum_k p_k \bs u_k \bs u_k^*,
\qquad
U_A \equiv UV^\dagger = \sum_k \bs u_k \bs v_k^*.
$$
Now we have
$$U_A |A| = (UV^\dagger U)DU^\dagger = \sum_{jk} p_k \langle \bs v_j,\bs u_k\rangle \bs u_j \bs u_k^*,$$
which in general differs from $|A| U_A=A$.