# $T=AU \iff T $ is a normal operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

This is Exercise 16.(c) from Conway's Functional Analysis book.

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T$ is a compact operator on $H$. Assuming the result that $\exists A$ positive operator and  $U$ a bounded operator such that $T=UA$

(NOTE: here $A= \sqrt {T^* T} $ and $U$ is the operator defined as in the construction of the polar decomposition i.e. $\|Uh\|=\|h\|$ when $h \perp \ker(T)$ and $Uh=0$ when $h \in\ker(T)$ i.e. $U(Ah)=Th$ when $h \perp \ker(A)=\bar{Ran(A)}$ and $Uh=0$ when $h\in\ker(A)$ ) ,

I have to prove :

> $T=AU \iff T $ is normal

I tried to compute products and tried to show the one direction that ($T=AU \implies T $ is normal) , but since $U$ is just assumed to be bounded, not unitary, got stuck!

EDIT :

For $T$ Normal ,assuming $U$ to be unitary ( we can do that provided $T$ is normal), have been able to show that $AU=UA$ .

But for the other direction, ($T=AU=UA \implies T$ normal), got, $T^*T=AU^*UA$ and $TT^* = AU^*UA$ . So if U is at least normal, we are done! (as mentioned in an answer) . But , we have to be careful, because by construction of $U$ and $A$, it is not clear to me how is $U$ normal. ( since we are trying to show that $T$ is normal, we cannot assume beforehand that $U$ is unitary, like the other direction)

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read through the exercise in Conway's book
(Second edition from 1990, Chapter II, §7, Exercise 16, Part c, it's on page 59),
and it deals with the polar decomposition of $\,T=U\!A\,$ for some bounded operator $T$ on $H$. The bounded operators $A$ and $U$ are **uniquely** determined by $T$ when asked to satisfy

- $A=\sqrt{T^*T}=|T| $
- $U$ is a partial isometry with $\,\ker U=\ker T\,$ and
  $\,\operatorname{im} U =\overline{\,\operatorname{im}T}\,$.

*Note that* $\,U^*\!\!\:U\,$ is the projector onto $\,\overline{\operatorname{im}|T|}\,$ which implies $\,A=U^*\!\!\:U\!A=U^*T$.
Multiplying with $U$ from the left yields $\,UU^*T=T$.

*Consequences* for the polar decomposition of $\,T^*$
$$=(U\!A)^*=AU^*= U^*\big(U\!AU^*\big)$$
Thus $\,U|T|U^*=\,|T^*|\,$ and $\,T^*=U^*|T^*|\,$ is the (unique) polar decomposition of $\,T^*$.

---

In the sequel $T$ is not required to be compact. I would guess that mentioning that property is due to the early placement of the exercise in the book in which Conway proceeds from the special to the more general.

---

It is shown that $\:T=AU\iff T$ is normal.

"$\,\Longrightarrow\,$"
If $T=U\!A=AU\,$ then $T^*=AU^*=U^*\!A$, so the assumption tells us that $A$ also commutes with $U^*$. Hence
$$\,T^*= U^*\big(U\!AU^*\big)= U^*UU^*\!A = U^*\!A$$
is the polar decomposition of $\,T^*$. We have $\,UT^*=A\,$ by the above "Note that ..." applied to $\,T^*$, and conclude that $T\,T^*=A\,UT^*=A^2=T^*T$.

"$\,\Longleftarrow\,$"
$\,T=U\!A\,$ yields $\,T^*=AU^*$. Hence $\,UA^2U^* =T\,T^*=T^*T= A^2\,$ by normality. Taking the positive square-root (which is unique) gives
$\,U\!AU^* = A$, being equivalent to $\,UA = A\,U$ by the properties of $U$.

Comment: Please explain how you get "Note that one always has $^*=$"  and also from that how you get $UT^*=A$ in the first part.

Comment: @Coherent 
Good action from yours to ask for details, it improved the answer!
And thanks for the bounty award.

Answer (score 1):

With $T=AU$ you get $TT^* = AUU^*A$, and with $T=UA$ you get $T^*T=AU^*UA$. Now it is important that $U$ is unitary (or at least normal). In that case both expressions are the same.

If $U$ is not normal then this does not have to be true, take for example $A=\Bbb 1$ and $U=T$, then $T=UA=AU$ but $T$ is not necessarily normal.

Comment: Is it true that in $T=UA$, U is unitary iff T is normal. Then I think you can use that U is unitary in the first part. Otherwise you only know that T is normal implies U is unitary, so you can't use it to prove that T is normal.

Comment: No, take $U=T$ and $A=\Bbb1$. You can have normal $T$ without having unitary $U$. You have likely missed at some point that $T=UA$ is supposed to be the polar decomposition, which is unique and has $U$ unitary.