# An inequality for Schatten norms with a compact self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let $Q$ be a compact self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb R,\mathbb C)$. Notice that $(1-\Delta)^{s}$ is a positive (and hence self-adjoint) operator on $H$ for any $s>0$.

We denote by $\mathfrak S^p$ the Schatten space with norm $\|A\|_{\mathfrak S^p}=(\mathrm{Tr}|A|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

I am trying to show that, for $p>1$, $$\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}Q(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\|_{\mathfrak S^p}\leq \|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}|Q|^{\frac{1}{2}}\|_{\mathfrak S^{2p}}^2.$$

Some essential ingredients would be that $\|A^*\|_{\mathfrak S^p}=\|A\|_{\mathfrak S^p}$ for all $p\geq 1$, and that Schatten norms satisfy the Hölder inequality $\|AB\|_{\mathfrak S^r}\leq \|A\|_{\mathfrak S^{p}}\|B\|_{\mathfrak S^q}$ if $1/r=1/p+1/q$.

Another fact which may be useful: since $Q$ is self-adjoint, $Q\leq |Q|$, and therefore $(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}Q(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\leq (1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}|Q|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}$.

Comment: I have changed your title which was way too technical into a searchable and retrievable sentence. Do you agree ?

Comment: I suppose it was indeed a good idea. I shortened it slighlty without changing the meaning by replacing "Schatten spaces" and "norms" to "Schatten norms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J = \|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}Q\,(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\|_{\mathfrak S^p}$. The polar decomposition of $Q$ allows to write $Q = U \,|Q|$ for some operator $U$ with $U_{|\,\mathrm{Ker}|A|} = 0$ and $U_{|\,\overline{\mathrm{Ran}|A|}}$ is an isometry and which commutes with $|Q|$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038582/prove-that-the-polar-decomposition-of-normal-matrices-a-su-is-such-that-su)), that is $U\,|Q|\,U^* = |Q|$ and so taking the square root, $U\,|Q|^{1/2}\,U^* = |Q|^{1/2}$, so that $U\,|Q|^{1/2} = |Q|^{1/2}\,U$ (that is, $U$ also commutes with $|Q|^{1/2}$). Therefore, $Q = |Q|^{1/2}\,U\,|Q|^{1/2}$ which implies that
$$
J = \|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\,|Q|^{1/2}\,U\,|Q|^{1/2}\,(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\|_{\mathfrak S^p}
$$
and so by Hölder's inequality and the fact that $\|U\|_{\mathfrak S^\infty} = 1$
$$
J \leq \|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\,|Q|^{1/2}\|_{\mathfrak S^{2p}} \||Q|^{1/2}\,(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\|_{\mathfrak S^{2p}}.
$$
This and the fact that the Schatten norm is invariant by taking the adjoint lead to
$$
J \leq \|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}\,|Q|^{1/2}\|_{\mathfrak S^{2p}}^2.
$$