# Trace inequality for $\operatorname{Tr}(ABAB)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace

Is it true that for square matrices $A,B$ it holds that
$$\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)\operatorname{Tr}(ABAB)\le (\operatorname{Tr}(A^2 B))^2$$
maybe under some additional assumptions on $A,B$ like positive semidefinite?

**Background:** In a more general setting I obtained
$$\operatorname{Tr}(A\bar A)\operatorname{Tr}(AB\bar A \bar B)+\lvert\operatorname{Tr}(AB\bar A)\rvert^2+\cdots\ge 0$$
for complex-symmetric $A$ and general $B$, where $\bar A$ denotes the entry-wise complex conjugate. I am wondering whether the sum of the two terms above is always non-negative on their own without the rest of the sum. But then I noticed that even in the setting of real-valued matrices I do not know whether such an inequality might hold true.

Comment: If you'd like to prove that the sum is positive, wouldn't you rather want to prove that $$\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)\operatorname{Tr}(ABAB) \geq - (\operatorname{Tr}(A^2 B))^2$$ Interesting question either way.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is normal then the polar decomposition of $A$ can be written $A = U\,|A|$ with $U$ unitary and commuting with $A$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038582/prove-that-the-polar-decomposition-of-normal-matrices-a-su-is-such-that-su)) and so
$$
|\mathrm{Tr}(A^2B)|^2 = \left|\mathrm{Tr}\left(\sqrt{|A|}\,B\,\sqrt{|A|}\,U\,A\right)\right|^2
\\
\leq \mathrm{Tr}\left(\left|\sqrt{|A|}\,B\,\sqrt{|A|}\right|^2\right) \,\mathrm{Tr}(|A|^2)
\\
\leq \mathrm{Tr}(|A|\,B\,|A|\,B) \,\mathrm{Tr}(|A|^2)
$$
so in particular if $A$ is positive semi-definite, we get the reverse to your inequality
$$
|\mathrm{Tr}(A^2B)|^2 \leq \mathrm{Tr}(A\,B\,A\,B) \,\mathrm{Tr}(A^2).
$$

Comment: Does this assume that $B$ is Hermitian?

Comment: I was working with general complex matrices here. So the first part not (normal is slightly weaker than self-adjoint) and the second part yes (positivity implies self-adjointness for complex matrices)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample, namely
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\; B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then we have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)\operatorname{Tr}(ABAB)=6,\;
(\operatorname{Tr}(A^2 B))^2=4. 
$$
Also the converse inequality does not hold in general. Take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\; B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)\operatorname{Tr}(ABAB)=0,\;
(\operatorname{Tr}(A^2 B))^2=3. 
$$